# How to assign nvarchar and varchar in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, nvarchar

I have store procedure called thisSP which calls another sp called [theOtherStoreProcedure].

[in **thissp** there is nvarchar EventUrl parameter.]

```
EXEC dbo.TheOtherStoreProcedure     @EventID = @EventID
                                    ,
                                    ,
                                    ....................
                                    ,@EventUrl = @EventUrl
```

in **TheOtherStoreProcedure** I am assigning EventUrl's and inserting it to Table.However in TheOtherStoreProcedure EventUrl is varchar

```
@EventUrl = @EventUrl
```

**Question is** : is SQLServer doing nvarchar to varchar convert process doing automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server performs the implicit conversion from nvarchar to varchar provided the size of both the paramaters are compatible.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is the table of conversion in SQL Server

Comment: yeap, it is working great without doing any extra work, thank you